# Redux not dispatching action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-dnd

I'm using React-dnd combined with Redux but I can't dispatch an action. My action is called but the reducer is never called :

```
const spelSource = {
    drop(props, monitor) {
        updateD(monitor.getItem(), props.spel);
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    updateD: (newS, oldS) => updateDeck(newS, oldS),
};

export default connect(
    null, mapDispatchToProps
)(Spel)

Spel = DropTarget('spel', spelSource, collect)(Spel);
```

and in my action :

```
export function updateD(newS, oldS) {
    console.log("update");
    return function (dispatch) {
        return dispatch({
            type:"UPDATE_D",
            newS: newS,
            oldS: oldS
        });
    };
}
```

Finally the reducer :

```
    case 'UPDATE_D':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            d: finalUpdate(state, action)
        });
```

Is there a way to dispatch? Thanks!

Comment: You can replace that mapDispatchToProps with `const mapDispatchToProps = {
updateDeck
};` quite simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to dispatch *from* the action, but you need Redux to dispatch the action itself. Your action should just return an object with `type` property and payload (whatever else). The action gets wrapped in the `dispatch()` function by the `connect()` function with `mapDispatchToProps`. Traditionally, you do like this...

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateD: (newS, oldS) => dispatch(updateDeck(newS, oldS))
});
```

There are some shorter ways to do this [in this article](https://blog.benestudio.co/5-ways-to-connect-redux-actions-3f56af4009c8), but this is the traditional way. You can see that the `connect()` function takes this and will pass it through the `dispatch()` method of the Redux store.

Then, your action will just return the object:

```
export const UPDATE_D = 'UPDATE_D';

export const updateD = (newS, oldS) => ({
    type: UPDATE_D,
    newS,
    oldS
});
```

Finally, your reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case UPDATE_D:
    return {
      ...state,
      newS: action.newS,
      oldS: action.oldS
     };
     default:
       return state;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this.props` to properly dispatch that action from your component.

E.g, in `spelSource`, `this.props.updateD(monitor.getItem(), props.spel)`

Comment: Thanks for answering! The fact is when I do that I got this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateD' of undefined`

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' are you importing your function from redux?

Comment: Yes I'am importing it from my action

Answer (score 1):

may be an error that action returns a function instead of object. And this inner function is never called.

I would expect to see something like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateD: (newS, oldS) => dispatch({
            type:"UPDATE_D",
            newS: newS,
            oldS: oldS
        })
  }
}
```